If $\omega_{\xi, \eta}$ is positive then there exists $\zeta\in \mathcal{H}$ s.t. $\omega_{\xi, \eta}=\omega_{\zeta, \zeta}$
Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space and $\xi, \eta \in \mathcal{H}$. Let $\omega_{\xi, \eta}:\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})\to \mathbb{C}$ is defined by $\omega_{\xi, \eta}(x):=\langle x\xi, \eta\rangle$. Now I want to prove the following:

If $\omega_{\xi, \eta}$ is positive then there exists $\zeta\in \mathcal{H}$ s.t. $\omega_{\xi, \eta}=\omega_{\zeta, \zeta}$.

To prove this I first introduce the operators $e_{\xi, \eta}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ by:
$$
e_{\xi,\eta}(\zeta): = \langle \zeta, \eta \rangle \xi ~~ (\zeta \in \mathcal{H}) 
$$
I know the following facts:

$e_{\xi, \eta}$ is rank one operator and $e_{\xi, \xi}\ge 0$ for any $\xi, \eta$.
$\langle e_{\xi, \eta}(\zeta), \zeta \rangle = \omega_{\xi, \eta}(e_{\zeta, \zeta})$ for any $\xi, \eta, \zeta \in \mathcal{H}$.
any rank one projection is of the form $e_{\zeta, \zeta}$ for some unit vector $\zeta$.
$e_{\xi, \eta}= e_{\zeta, \zeta} \implies\omega_{\xi, \eta}= \omega_{\zeta, \zeta}$

Hence if $\omega_{\xi, \eta}$ is positive then by (1) and (2) $e_{\xi, \eta}$ is a positive rank one operator. Now I have a feelings that a positive rank one operator is a scalar multiple of a (rank one) projection. If this statement is true then we're done by (4).
Basically I need to prove that if $e_{\xi, \eta} \ge 0$ then it is a scalar multiple of some projection $e_{\zeta, \zeta}$.
If $e_{\xi, \eta}\ge 0$, what I get is that $\langle \xi, \eta \rangle e_{\xi, \eta}= e_{\xi, \eta} e_{\xi, \eta} = e_{\xi, \eta} e_{\xi, \eta}^*=\|\eta\|^2e_{\xi, \xi}$.
From this I can only get the assertion in the case when $\langle\xi, \eta \rangle \ne 0$.
May be I am complicating things. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

You’re nearly there. If either $\xi$ or $\eta$ is zero, $e_{\xi, \eta} = 0 = e_{0, 0}$. Otherwise, $\|\eta\|^2 e_{\xi, \xi}$ is nonzero and positive, so as $\langle \xi, \eta \rangle e_{\xi, \eta} = \|\eta\|^2 e_{\xi, \xi}$ is nonzero, we have $\langle \xi, \eta \rangle \neq 0$ and $e_{\xi, \eta} = \frac{1}{\langle \xi, \eta \rangle}\|\eta\|^2 e_{\xi, \xi}$. As $\|\eta\|^2 e_{\xi, \xi}$ is nonzero positive and $e_{\xi, \eta}$ is positive, we must have $\langle \xi, \eta \rangle$ is positive and thus $e_{\xi, \eta}$ is a positive multiple of $e_{\xi, \xi}$.
(A small note here is that you need a positive multiple of projection, not just an arbitrary scalar multiple.)
